# Regex for ensuring periods and underscores cannot be repeated

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not strong in Regex and would like to write a formula that disallows input with repeating periods and underscores. For example, the following should not be allowed:

`h..ello`

`__world`

`hel.....lo`

`world____`

A period or underscore can not be preceded or followed by another period or underscore respectively.

It's okay if they are mixed together like so:

`h._ell_.o` (This is a valid string)

`wor._._ld` (This is a valid string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the regex below:

```
var input = "he__lo";
var regex = new Regex(@"\.{2}|_{2}");

var valid = !regex.Match(input).Success;
```

The parts:

- "\.{2}" matches any occurrence of two dots
- "_{2}" mathes any occurrence of two undercores
- "|" means "or"

And of course any match of two is technically a hit for anything more than two.

Comment: Why did you need to add the rule for two dot-underscores? Is it needed?

Comment: You wanted "wor._._ld" to fail.  The rule for two dot-unserscores looks for two consecutive "._".

Comment: @user246392, did you want to invalidate dot-underscores in any order?

Comment: No, I said it was a valid string. Sorry for the confusion. A string is not valid only if a period or underscore repeats consecutively.

Comment: Don't know why I read that.  Confusion is my fault.  Editing the answer.  Stand by.

Comment: Thank for the edit. I tested it and it's working fine!